Parsing command line in Python
I'm trying to parse Windows command line to executable (like "python.exe"), script file / EXE file that the command runs, and arguments that are passed to this file.
This is what I've done so far:
def parse_cmd(cmd):
    executable = filepath = args = ""
    split_cmd = shlex.split(cmd, posix=False)

    # Find files in command line, without including python.exe
    files = [s for s in split_cmd if s.strip('"').endswith((".py", ".bat", ".exe")) and s not in sys.executable]

    if files:
        filepath = files[0]
        i = split_cmd.index(filepath)
        executable_list = split_cmd[:i]  # Get the elements before the file
        args_list = split_cmd[i + 1:]  # Get the elements after the file

        filepath = filepath.strip('"')
        executable = " ".join(executable_list)
        args = " ".join(args_list)

    return executable, filepath, args

Are there better ways to implement it?
Examples of calling this method:
cmd1 = "python.exe foo.py --arg1 foo --arg2 bar"
res1 = parse_cmd(cmd1)
print(res1)
cmd2 = 'test.exe -arg1 "foo"'
res2 = parse_cmd(cmd2)
print(res2)
cmd3 = "echo test"
res3 = parse_cmd(cmd3)
print(res3)
cmd4 = r'py -3 -E "test new\test.py"'
res4 = parse_cmd(cmd4)
print(res4)

Output:
('python.exe', 'foo.py', '--arg1 foo --arg2 bar')
('', 'test.exe', '-arg1 "foo"')
('', '', '')
('py -3 -E', 'test new\\test.py', '')


This might be better suited to [codereview.se] but read their guidelines before posting

Soo why not just return shlex.split?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

@KamilCuk, because it doesn't split the command to the three parts: Executable, script path and arguments.

@OrangeDog, argparse only parses the arguments of the script file. Not the whole command line. Also the arguments aren't known in advance.

There is only executable and arguments. There is no script. What about bash --rcfile script script arg1? What about python -m script -c script arg1? You want to handle each interpreter arguments? What about sed -f script1 -f script2 -f script3? grep -f script? perl -M-? Each command is unique, there is command and arguments, there is no "script". What should happen with env env env python script? Are you restricting your parsing to a specific set of commands and you want to reimplement these commands command line option parsing?

The problem itself - parsing command line option and splitting it to parts - is tackled in many places by bash-completion project. For completion, you have to know if code is completing --rcfile option of -o option or -c or script option of bash executable. Each and every command is handled separately in bash-completion - there is no general solution (there is parsing pyhton --help output with a regex, but it is not foolproof).

@KamilCuk, yes, it's for specific set of commands. It's for passing the script path and its arguments separately. If "python.exe / "py -3 -E" comes before the script path, need to include it too.

Then you have to actually parse the arguments, for example with argparse, and it all will be in best-efforted manner. Command line options may and will change with releases. Another example test.exe -arg1 foo. -arg1 could be a script, it could be ('test.exe', '-arg1', 'foo'). I do not understand what is the general intention. it's for specific set of commands which commands?

I meant that the arguments need to be separate from the script path. However, the arguments themselves need to be in one string.

Where is cmd coming from? If it's the command line of the current process, then sys has already done all the work for you.

@OrangeDog, it's from a string. Not current process.

This code here should run more optimally:
import shlex
def parse_cmd(cmd):
    split_cmd = shlex.split(cmd, posix=False)
    executable = filepath = args = ""
    for i, part in enumerate(split_cmd):
        if part.strip('"').endswith((".py", ".bat", ".exe")):
            executable = " ".join(split_cmd[:i]) if i > 0 else split_cmd[0]
            filepath = part.strip('"')
            args = " ".join(split_cmd[i + 1:])
            break
        elif i == 0:
            executable = part
    if not filepath and len(split_cmd) > 1:
        args = " ".join(split_cmd[1:])
    return executable, filepath, args


Thanks for helping. However, it doesn't give the correct outputs. Running the examples above with this function gives the following outputs: ('python.exe', 'python.exe', 'foo.py --arg1 foo --arg2 bar')
('test.exe', 'test.exe', '-arg1 "foo"')
('echo', '', 'test')
('py -3 -E', 'test new\test.py', '')
